# Resolve rowcolor and column separator clash?

Tags: tables, color, siunitx, rowcolor

I want to create a table with Text aligned around the separator "V-" and color it using \rowcolor. The normal column separator @{V-} doesn't work with \rowcolors, thus I'm searching for a way to do it in another way.  Is it possible to use the neat S column of the siunitx package? I tried it with

```
\usepackage[input-decimal-markers={V-}]{siunitx}
```

and

```
\usepackage[input-signs={V-}]{siunitx}
```

but it throws errors.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
with @{V-}:\\
\rowcolors{1}{black!10}{}
\begin{tabular}{|r@{V-}l|}
\hline
C & CV-\\\hline
CC & CV-\\\hline
h1C & V-\\\hline
\end{tabular}

with c and tabcolsep=0pt:\\
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\rowcolors{1}{black!10}{}
\begin{tabular}{|rcl|}
\hline
C & V- & CV-\\\hline
CC & V- & CV-\\\hline
h1C & V- & V-\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

So far, the version with tabcolsep=0pt works best, but the table is quite ugly without any separator spaces. If I just use S, siunitx of course says “Invalid numerical input '-'.” Any ideas?

PS: I've read [205041](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205041/rowcolor-and-custom-column-separators) and [289298](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289298/table-xcolor-rowcolor-broken-text), but they don't answer my question.

Edit:
I don't need to use siunitx, if anybody knows a different solution…

Comment: [294579](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294579/why-does-rowcolors-cut-matrix-delimiter) seems to be the same problem, but involving matrices. Unfortunately, so does the brilliant solution of @egreg there – I don't think I can use this in any way, or can I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even after several time trying I could not resolve the issue using `siunitx`, but I found a way using `dcolumn` and want to share my solution (which is more like a workaround though):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\begin{document}
\rowcolors{2}{black!10}{}
\begin{tabular}{lD{-}{\mbox{-}}{-1}}
\toprule
some things & \multicolumn{1}{c}{random root shapes} \\
\midrule
something & \mbox{CV}-\mbox{CV-} \\
something & \mbox{CCV}-\mbox{CV-} \\
something & \mbox{h1CV}-\mbox{V-} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The reason for all the mboxing is that `dcolumn` sets the cell in math mode. The boxes prevent this and make it possible to enter other occurences of the alignment sign inside the cell.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard separator `@{V-}` in `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` and you will have the expected output if you use the tools of `nicematrix` for the colors of the rows (a command `\rowcolors{black!10}{}` at the beginning of the array).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{|r@{V-}l|}[color-inside]
\hline
\rowcolors{black!10}{}
C & CV-\\\hline
CC & CV-\\\hline
h1C & V-\\\hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]